# AWS Main Routing Table

Tags: amazon-web-services

As I understand, by default, all subnets will be associated with "Main" route table which we can see clearly from the below diagram.

However, the point which contradicting in the below picture is main route table Route Table:rtb-0ef68d70 didnt show any subnet associations like you see "You do not have any subnet associations".

Just below that, the statement "The following subnets have not been explicitly associated with any route tables and are therefore associated with the main route table:" implies that main route table is associated with subnets ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct yes. The subnets are associated with the main route table in this case but not explicitly.
I'd advice you to create the route tables you need. Associate them with the subnets you want and don't use the main route table.